# pd.read_csv is reading less rows than the expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to read a csv file, beforehand I already know the file has 13,000 rows, and pandas reads just 9,500 without raising any errors... but here is the thing, when I use 'to_csv()' method, and open the file with excel, it has 13,000 rows, so I don't understand what's happening here...

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv(file
                   ,delimiter='|'
                   ,sep='|'
                   ,low_memory= False
                  )
```

Comment: Can you check and try this solution it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161769/not-reading-all-rows-while-importing-csv-into-pandas-dataframe

Comment: what is the output of below code? `print(raw_data.shape)`

Comment: *pandas reads just 9,500* ... how do you know? What line of code shows this?

Comment: when I run raw_data.shape I got (9,500, 34), when I export this DataFrame to csv again and I open it in excel, I've got 13,000 rows and 34 cols...I tried this with several files, and this is the only file that show this problem...and I didn't find any pattern that can allow me to fix this issue

Comment: `delimiter` is an alias for `sep` (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once and never really looked into why it added extra rows although i found out that using `to_xlsx()` and then re-saving it `to_csv()` it didn't add the extra lines.

Comment: yes, but the thing is I need those 13,000, I read the csv file in order to make some changes to the data, and at the end of my process I need to have the entire file again, but in order to give a quick look to my DataFrame, I use 'info()' method, and it retrieves me 9,500 for the value count in each field.

Comment: I don't think i understand what your issue is here then. Can you make a more specific rephrase?

Comment: I have a txt file with 13,000 rows, when I import it using pandas read_csv() method, I get a 9,500 rows dataframe, if I ask for the shape, I have (9500, 34), and when I export the df using to_csv() and open it with excel, I got 13,000 rows...so I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161769/not-reading-all-rows-while-importing-csv-into-pandas-dataframe but I don't understand what's happening...

Answer (score 0):

I used this post to fix my problem an it worked

[Not reading all rows while importing csv into pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161769/not-reading-all-rows-while-importing-csv-into-pandas-dataframe)

If somebody can explain why is this happen, and why I need use the parameter "quoting" I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that some lines contain text with newline characters.

Here's an example of such a situation:

```
%%writefile file.csv
c1|c2|c3|c4
a|b|c|d
1|"2
x"|3|4
```

`file.csv` has 4 lines (header plus three lines) but the last two lines are actually one line, this is because there's a text field containing a newline:

```
c1|c2|c3|c4
a|b|c|d
1|"2
x"|3|4
```

When you import the file with pandas you correctly get header plus 2 rows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('file.csv'
             ,sep='|'
             ,low_memory= False
            )

#    c1     c2  c3  c4
# 0   a      b   c   d
# 1   1   2\nx   3   4
```

The string `"2\nx"` causes the file to occupy two lines (`"` is the default `quotechar` -- the character used to denote the start and end of a quoted item).

To detect such lines you can use `awk`

```
!awk -v FS='|' '{ if (NF<4) print }'  file.csv
# 1|"2
# x"|3|4
```

**Note:** `delimiter` is an alias for `sep` (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

If you use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` you get 3 rows in the dataframe but that's not what you want in this case:

```
import csv
pd.read_csv('file.csv'
             ,sep='|'
             ,low_memory= False
             ,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
            )

   c1   c2   c3  c4
0   a   b   c   d
1   1   "2  NaN NaN
2   x"  3   4   NaN
```