# Length of second csv file not equal to base file using np.select

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to use np.select to merge the values of two columns into a new column from file1 and write it into file2. However the length (amount of rows) is not the same in both files at the end. For some reason, there are always a couple of hundred of lines missing.

I have three columns: 'Time', "LSB", "MSB" with each about 1000 values

Here is an extract of my code:

```
file2 = File_Name_G() #This is a function to define the name of file2

imu_gyr = pd.read_csv(file1, index_col=0)
imu_gyr["Gyr_x"] = np.select([(imu_gyr["LSB"] + imu_gyr["MSB"]*256) > 32767], [(imu_gyr["LSB"] + imu_gyr["MSB"]*256 - 65536)/1000], (imu_gyr["LSB"] + imu_gyr["MSB"]*256)/1000]

imu_gyr.to_csv(file2)
```

My code shows no errors and I am really confused as to why this is happening. I thought it could  have something to do with processing power, but the length of my file1 has no real influence on the amount of lines missing in file2.

Has anyone had a similar problem or can someone help me solve this?

Thanks a lot! :)
Sam

Comment: This is not possible unless there is some bug in the numpy source. NumPy may misbehave for pandas dataframe as input. Can you try to first extract the numpy array from the pandas dataframe (using ``.value``) and then try to run your code? You can then convert the output numpy array to the pandas dataframe to save results in some file.

Comment: @TirthPatel I have realized that the problem is with the `pd.read_csv` as it is not reading the entire data (not reading all the lines). I have change that line to `pd.read_csv(file1, index_col=0, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, error_bad_lines=False)` as recommended by [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161769/not-reading-all-rows-while-importing-csv-into-pandas-dataframe]. It is working better but still leaving out some rows at the end...

Comment: Have you tried to investigate why that happens? My best guess would be non-ascii or non-unicode characters that pandas is not able to interpret. But I am not familiar with pandas source code so I can't say...